# Invalid color argument in pygame when trying to gradient

Tags: python, colors, pygame

I'm trying to change each value of RBG from one color to another target color.
My window is 700 units in width and I'm trying to draw 350 rectangles, each 2 pixels wide with a very slightly adjusted color.

I'm doing this using a for-loop but there is an invalid color argument error. I'm also sure there is a better method to do this, but I'm trying to see if this would work.

I'm a very beginner to pygame- excuse my lack of knowledge.

```
red_v = 199
green_v = 229
blue_v = 255

x = 0
y = 0

for i in range(350):

    pygame.draw.rect(screen, (red_v, green_v, blue_v), (x, y, 2, 500))

    red_v -= 3
    green_v -= 2
    blue_v -= 3

    x += 2
```

I have tried storing my RBG under a variable name like this:

```
for i in range(350):

    GRADIENT = [red_v, green_v, blue_v]
    pygame.draw.rect(screen, GRADIENT, (x, y, 2, 500))

    red_v -= 3
    green_v -= 2
    blue_v -= 3
```

Makes no difference. I'm sure this is probably a very simple fix that I cannot see just yet.

Answer (score 1):

You have to make sure that the color channels are always in range [0, 255]. The can't be negativ:

```py
GRADIENT = [max(0, red_v), max(0, green_v), max(0, blue_v)]
pygame.draw.rect(screen, GRADIENT, (x, y, 2, 500))
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to do

```py
pygame.draw.rect(screen, (red_v, green_v, blue_v), pygame.Rect(x1,y1,x2,y2))
```

Check this out:
https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/how-to-draw-rectangle-in-pygame/

Comment: Tried it just now, it's still the color argument that's invalid. I've used the drawing rectangle feature many times in the rest of my code and have followed the same format and it works flawlessly. This is the first time I'm trying to change the RGB values individually though.

As for "pygame.Rect(x1,y1,x2,y2)", rather than 2 coordinate positions the last 2 arguments are actually just my width and height

Comment: Is there like any error code or anything?

Comment: Traceback (most recent call last):
line 36, in <module>
    pygame.draw.rect(screen, (red_v, green_v, blue_v), pygame.Rect(x, y, 2, 500))
ValueError: invalid color argument

Comment: Did it happen on the second time the `for` loop ran?

Comment: How would I check that? also thanks for helping me troubleshoot

Comment: you could add a`print('hi')` to check, if it prints hi one time then the error happens on the second time the loop is ran

Comment: you could try specifing an alpha value in the colour, like `(red_v,green_v,blue_v,255)`